# Divergent Expected Value

Tags: probability, statistics

Is it possible that the expected value $\left \langle D \right \rangle$ of a random variable $D$ diverges for $N\rightarrow \infty $ ?

Where $N$ is the number of examples used to calculate the expected value $\left \langle D \right \rangle$.

Comment: What would the random variable $D$ have to look like?

Comment: a function of N ?

Comment: No, the random variable stays fixed, but you're taking many samples of it.

Answer (score 1):

The expected value of a random variable does not depend on the number of samples. What depends on the number of samples is the *sample mean*, which is

$$\bar D_N = \frac 1N \sum D_i$$

The law of large numbers tells you that if $D \in L^1$ (that is, $E[D]$ is finite) then the sample mean converges to $E[D]$. So to have the sample mean diverge, you have to look at random variables for which the expected value does not exist (or is infinite)

Comment: And there is the well known example of a random variable $X$ which takes the value $2^n$ with probability $1/2^n$ for all $n=1,2,3,...$, and you can see easily that the expected value is infinite.